# Firebase image in storage gets rewritten and only last two are kept

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

In my Firebase project, the user has the ability to upload an image and it is stored in a folder called `images` on Firebase Storage.

However, whenever I am testing it out by uploading an image, the folder only shows the 2 most recent images I have uploaded. I would like it to keep all uploaded images.

Has anyone else run into a similar problem? I don't know if the problem lies within my code or in Firebase but here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage

class PostViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var noteTextField: UITextField!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    var imageName = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpeg"
    var imageURL = ""


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        imagePicker.delegate = self

    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = selectedImage

        }
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
    }




    @IBAction func cameraTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func choosePhotoTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePicker,animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func postTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        let imagesFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
        if let image = imageView.image{
            if let imageData : Data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1){
                imagesFolder.child(imageName).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print(error)

                    }else{
                        imagesFolder.child(self.imageName).downloadURL { (url, error) in
                            if let imageURL = url?.absoluteString{
                                self.imageURL = imageURL
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "successSegue", sender: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Does the problem possibly exist in Firebase's settings?

Comment: Well, your image name is static. See here `imagesFolder.child(imageName).putData` and then `var imageName = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpeg"`. That property is assigned only when the PostViewController is instantiated. In other words if the PostViewController is being shown and the user taps a post, it writes it out the image with a name. If they tap a different post/image, it will write that out with the same name. The imageName property is never mutated beyond it's initial uuid string. OR is this controller used for every cell or row? That's a little unclear

Comment: The 2 images within the folder on firebase all have different names. But somehow the folder only keeps 2 within it and just deletes previous uploads.

Comment: Correct. Every tap overwrites the existing picture with the same name. Just to double check, I copy and pasted your code into a project and that's what it does. As far as having two names, that didn't happen so it tells me there is additional code outside of the posted code that's causing trouble. You will probably want to name the picture when the user taps it, not when the controller loads, that way they will have unique names.

Comment: This is the only code for this ViewController. I found out the reason why it only shows 2 images is because I simulated the app multiple times but when it is already running and i post again it the new image is named the same as the previous. But when i quit the app then launch it again a new image has a different name. How could i write that in code to rename a new image after the previous one is successful? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that when the PostViewController is instantiated, the imageName var is populated and every time an image is tapped to be saved, it will save with the same name. The name would change if, for example, the app was restarted as a new PostViewController would be instantiated which would create a new imageName property

The fix is to move the imageName property so it's created each time a user taps

```
    class PostViewController: UIViewController,UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var noteTextField: UITextField!
        var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
  |---      //var imageName = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpeg"  //move this
  |      var imageURL = ""
  |      .
  |      .
  |       @IBAction func postTapped(_ sender: Any) {
  |   
  |           let imagesFolder = Storage.storage().reference().child("images")
  |           if let image = imageView.image {
  |              if let imageData : Data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) {  
  |---->            let imageName = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpeg"  //to here  
                    imagesFolder.child(imageName).putData(imageData, metadata: nil) { (metaData, error) in
                        if let error = error{
```